# String Manipulation to construct a substring

Tags: java, linked-list

Given a string A consisting of N characters and a string B consisting of M characters, returns the number of times A must be stated such that B is a substring of the repeated string. If B can never be a substring of the repeated A then your functions should return -1.

EX:

```
A = "abcd"
B = "cdabcdab"
```

Function should return 3 because after stating string A three times we obtain the string "abcdabcdabcd". String B is a substring of this string.

**Attempt:** currently stuck here - trying to construct and algorithm first before I begin to write code - can really use a push here. I'm trying to think of the minimum length A has to be before it contains B as a substring. Not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: Show us your code till now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have most of the algorithm in your description:

> ...after stating string A three times we obtain the string "abcdabcdabcd". String B is a substring of this string.

So you'll need to create a temporary variable to hold the "multiplied" string, then check if string B is in the temporary variable. You'll also need a variable to hold the number of times you multiplied A. In summary, while string B is not contained in string A, keep multiplying string A.

Here's an example:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(substrInMultiple("abcd", "cdabcdab"));
    }

    public static int substrInMultiple(String A, String B) {
        String multiple = A;
        int multipleCount = 1;
        while(!multiple.contains(B)) {
            multiple += A;
            multipleCount++;
        }
        return multipleCount;
    }
}
```

Beware, though. It's possible to have a string that will never be a substring of another, no matter how many times it's multiplied. That would create an infinite loop.

Comment: "It's possible to have a string that will never be a substring of another, no matter how many times it's multiplied" - this is the meat of the problem. How to detect if B can ever be a substring of A

Answer (score 3):

The idea is first to keep self-appending A until it becomes larger or equal to B (let's call it A+). This would handle the case of B lying completely within A+. 
If it doesn't then this is a case of B wrapping around A+, either from front or back. For front wrapping, prefix A+ with A and for back-wrapping suffix A+ with a. Check after each of these wrappings if B is now a substring of A+. If B isn't a substring even now, then it won't be ever.

Here's a solution in Java.

```
private static int times(String A, String B) {      

    StringBuffer aPlus = new StringBuffer(A);
    int times = 1;
    while (aPlus.length() < B.length()) {
        aPlus.append(A);
        times++;
    }

    if (aPlus.indexOf(B) != -1) {
        return times;
    }

    // prefix 
    aPlus.append(A);
    if (aPlus.indexOf(B) != -1) {
        return ++times;
    }

    //suffix
    aPlus.insert(0, A);
    if (aPlus.indexOf(B) != -1) {
        return ++times;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: [This is a Google interview question](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/google-interview-experience-set-7-software-engineering-intern/)

Answer (score 0):

```
public int solution(String A, String B) {
    int count = 0;
    while(A.length() < B.length()) {
        A += A;
        count++;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length() - B.length(); ++i) {
        if(A.substring(i, i + B.length()).equalsIgnoreCase(B)) {
            return count;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maximum repetition would be equal to **1 + B.length/A.length** , if possible.

Also verify upfront if repetition is possible or not.

```
  int formSubString(String A, String B) {
            Set<Character> set1 = new HashSet<>();
            for (char x: A.toCharArray()){
                set1.add(x);
            }

            Set<Character> set2 = new HashSet<>();
            for (char x: B.toCharArray()){
                set2.add(x);
            }

            if (!set1.containsAll(set2)){
                return -1;
            }
            int counter = 1;

            // maxCounter would be more than 1 of B.length/A.length if possible
            int maxCounter = B.length()/A.length()+1;
            String newA  = A;
            while(counter<= maxCounter){
                newA = newA+A;
                counter++;
                if (newA.contains(B)){
                    return counter;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
```